# Incorrect timestamp when requesting kline data

Tags: python, binance

I am testing requests for kline data from binance with a mind to eventually pass historical timestamps  from a dataframe. Currently the response is not what I expect.

```
import requests
from time import time

timestamp = int(time() - 60)

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines'
params = {
  'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
  'startTime': timestamp,
  'interval': '1m',
  'limit': "1"
}

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.json())
print(timestamp)
```

I also print the timestamp just to confirm that it is what I expect but this code returns OHLCV data from 2017 despite me trying to pass a very recent timestamp. If I state that timestamp = 1656694823 (random date from 2022) I still cannot retrieve the correct kline data.

Answer (score 0):

Changed timestamp to this

```
timestamp = int(((time() - 60) * 1000))
```

All good now.